# Hibernate update Primary Key, Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I dont know what happened, but before it worked (so I think)

We have following error:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Entity

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "VIN", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 17)
    public String getVin() {
        return this.vin;
    }

    public void setVin(String vin) {
        this.vin = vin;
    }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateCar(ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute("objectAttribute") Car car) {

    carService.update(car);

    return "redirect: details";
}
```

Webpage

```
<form:label path="vin">VIN</form:label>
<form:input path="vin"/>
```

What I am doing - I try update object Car where Primary Key is VIN.

Trying to change the id (car vin) generates an error as above, but editing other fields is correct (object updated).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not change the ID of a Hibernate entity. It's immutable.

You can delete the entity, and recreate it, but that will obviously cause problems if rows have a foreign key reference to this entity's row. That's why PKs should always be treated as immutable. If, as you should, you used an auto-generated, purely technical ID, you would never have to change the value of an entity ID. Functional primary keys must be avoided at all cost, precisely because functional values always change one day or another.

Comment: I just have to add the usual id and set vin number as normal field? I get it